# Application of p-adic valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Happy new year, I need help with solving the following problem

Let $p$ be a prime number, $f(X)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_{i}X^{i}\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $c_{p}(f):=min\{v_{p}(a_{i})|i=0,...,n\}$, $v_{p}:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Z}\cup\{ \infty\}$ is the unique extension of the p-adic valuation.

i) For $g,h\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ the following holds: $c_{p}(g*h)=c_{p}(g)+c_{p}(h)$

ii) $f(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ if and only if $c_p(f)\geq0$ for all prime numbers $p$.

i) I know that I have to find a $r$ such that $v_{p}(d_r)=c_{p}(g)+c_{p}(h)$ holds but I'm not sure how to do that. $d_{j}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^ja_{i}b_{j-i}$, this is obtained by multiplying two elements $g,h\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$, $g(X)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_{i}X^{i}$, $h(X)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^mb_{i}X^{i}$,  and we get $(g*h)(X)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n+m}d_{i}X^{i}.$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U_1,U_2 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. Iff $c_p(U_j) = k_j$ then $$U_j(X) = p^{k_j} (a_j X^{n_j}+ V_j(X))+p^{k_j+1} W_j(X)$$ with $V_j,W_j \in \mathbb{Z}[X],\deg(V_j) < n_j, p \nmid a_j$.

Then $$U_1(X)U_2(X) = p^{k_1+k_2}(a_1 a_2 X^{n_1+n_2}+V_3(X)) + p^{k_1+k_2+1} W_3(X)$$
with $V_3,W_3 \in \mathbb{Z}[X],\deg(V_3) < n_1+n_2, p \nmid a_1a_2$.

thus $$c_p(U_1U_2) = k_1+k_2 = c_p(U_1)+c_p(U_2)$$

---

Note we can state it with the big-O notation  : if $U_j(X) = p^{k_j} a_j X^{n_j} + O(p^{k_j} X^{n_j-1})+O(p^{k_j+1})$ then $U_1(X)U_2(X) = p^{k_1+k_2} a_1a_2 X^{n_1+n_2} + O(p^{k_1+k_2} X^{n_1+n_2-1})+O(p^{k_1+k_2+1})$